# Selecting a new object without grouping in linq?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I am trying to write a query to collect the Job number, start date, customer name, Model, and completion date for jobs at my work. To get this info, I look at 3 different tables, using joins to put them together. Here are the three tables:

STAGE - (stages each job goes through during production)

ORDER - (this is where I get the customer's name)

JOBS (start date, completion date, job number, model)

So most of the info is from the JOBS table. But I'm joining onto the ORDER table by Job Number (JobNum) to obtain the customer's name. Here's what the query looks like. I created it in SQL before I tried to translate it into one of my ViewModels:

```
var CompletedTrucksQuery = 
  (from FA in context.JOBS
    join ORD        in context.ORDER    on FA.ORGANIZATION_ID   equals ORD.ORGANIZATION_ID
    where FA.ORDER_NUMBER   == ORD.ORDER_NUMBER
    join StageF     in context.STAGE on FA.JobNum      equals StageF.JobNum
    where StageF.StageID   == 325
    join TruckComp  in context.STAGE on FA.JobNum      equals TruckComp.JobNum
    where TruckComp.StageID == 327
    join INSP       in context.STAGE on FA.JobNum      equals INSP.JobNum
    where INSP.StageID       == 487
    orderby StageF.CompDate descending, FA.JobNum ascending
    select new {FA.JobNum, FA.StartDate, ORD.CUSTOMER_NAME, FA.MODEL_NAME, StageF.CompDate});
```

At this point, I'm wanting to select the

Job number (from JOBS),

the start date, (From JOBS),

the Customer's name (from ORDER),

the Model of product (from JOBS),

and the date it was completed in StageF (from STAGE)

as you can see in my select statement. I DO have an object to hold each of these called CompJob, and have tried to do a 'group by' and select a new CompJob and set the properties, but I can't seem to group it right and get 'access' to all of the properties I want to set. Here's an excerpt of what I'm talking about:

```
 group new {FA.JobNum, O = ORD} by StageF into grp
                                        select new CompletedTruck
                                        {
                                            JobNum = grp.Key.JobNum,
                                            StartDate = grp. //???
                                        }
```

As you can tell I stopped, because for some reason I couldn't 'find' the start date. I know it's something to do with my grouping. I'm very new to linq and databases, in general.

**MY QUESTION:** What's the best way I can select these columns of interest into my

```
ObservableCollection<CompJob> CompJobList;
```

so that I may use it in my scrollviewer in a view?

Comment: Hi, so the context is actually using a custom 'Flavor' I guess, created by corporate at my job...not sure how much info I can even give you on that.

Comment: oh, LINQ to entities and the 'select new CompletedTruck' should be 'select  new CompJob', just to prevent confusion, I missed that in editing

Comment: *I DO have an object to hold each of these called CompJob* So why the grouping? Create `CompJob`s right away: `select new CompJob { JobNum = FA.JobNum, ... }` etc.

Comment: So I did that, and it works. But isn't my query going to return multiple rows? Will doing this actually return many CompJob objects, which I can then put into my ObservableCollection<CompJob>? Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: That's the problem with joins vs. using navigation properties as recommended. I can't see the multiplicity of the relations. I think you should *at least* change the joins to `TruckComp` and `INSP` to navigation properties and use these in a `where` statement.

Comment: grp is a List<> object so StartDate = grp.Select(x => x.StartDate).Min()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for helping me out. I solved the issue and this is what I did. I followed Gert Arnold's suggestion of selecting a new CompJob object. This would set each row of the query to a new object:

```
select new CompJob {JobNum = FA.JobNum, StartDate = FA.StartDate, Customer = ORD.CUSTOMER_NAME,.....}
```

and then said

```
).ToList();
```

At the end of  the query. Then I set my ObservableCollection to the list returned by my query:

```
CompJobList = CompletedTrucksQuery ;
```

Thanks again for helping me out; I know I'm new to all of this!